# Python : Error on getting List of 8 Highest (max value) Elements from an Array

Tags: python, arrays, list, dataframe, sorting

I've applied a logistic regression model on my dataset in Python, I'm predicting on the train set, to achieve a list of 8 elements that have the maximum value from that array. I've applied a sort method to get all the values in the descending order to achieve this but I get an error on the key keyword.

Any help would be appreciated. I've attached photos of my data frame as well as the code.

[Photo : Data Frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V3xDr.png)

[Photo : Array of values predicted by the Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3wjAp.png)

[Photo : Sorted Values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6IgNL.png)

```
x= df[['Hour','Minute','Seconds','Month','Year']]
y= df['Target']

xtrain, xtest, ytrain, ytest = train_test_split(x,y,test_size=0.20,random_state=10, 
shuffle=True)


from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
lr = LogisticRegression()
lr.fit(xtrain , ytrain)
predicting=lr.predict_proba(xtrain)
predicting[0,:]
predicting.sort()

arr = predicting
arr.sort(key=lambda x:x[0,:],reverse=True)
```

Comment: If you just want to reverse the array, you don't need to sort it again. You  can just reverse it with a reverse slice (`a[::-1]`, although if you just want the last eight elements, you could do that in the same slice (`a[-1:-9:-1]`). Also I have no idea what you expect that key function to accomplish.

Comment: I've tried the slice you wrote but I'm still not getting 8 elements with the maximum values. I'm somehow getting the same number of unordered elements as before.

Comment: in case it wasn't obvious, I was assuming you would do the slice after you sorted `predicting`.

Comment: Yes it was quite obvious, I am doing it after sorting predicting but still somehow not getting just 8 elements